# Precision of reading in file

Tags: c++, precision

I am working in C++ and having issues with the precision of reading in a double

```
input_file>>temp_double;
```

the number in the file is something like 1234.567 but when it reads in, it reads as 1234.56699999999. So how can I get it to read as it is in the file, I use the amount of decimals in later functions so I need it to be proper. the numbers in the file range from 3-5 decimal places

Comment: Not all numbers that you can express as a string of decimal digits can be represented by a built-in floating point type. You have to accept and live with that.

Comment: Are you sure that `1234.567` can be represented as "exact" double ?

Comment: Does the file contain text or binary data? Computations with doubles do not have the concept of decimal places, or the concept of "proper."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`float` and `double` store their data using an IEEE standard that stores a sign bit, an exponent, and a fractional value.  Most decimal values will not be exactly precise when stored due to the base 10 to base 2 conversion of the fractional portion.

Also, mathematically, 1234.566999999999999.... = 1234.567

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, a `double` cannot represent many decimal values precisely.  It stores its data in binary, and rounds off eventually.  Many numbers which can be represented precisely in decimal have non-terminating representations in binary.

If you need precise representation, look at e.g [Boost::Multiprecision](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/boost_multiprecision/intro.html).